# What is $B^{-1} y$? Linear Algebra/Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[Link to problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujVyD.png)

I have included the question and its solution in the image above. In the part where the solution says "we know that $y$ is in the span of $b_1$ and $b_2$ so $x_3 = 0$", I do not get how and why $x_3 = 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'$y $ is in the span of the first and second column of $B $' is stated in the question. So basically we are told in the question statement that for some $x_1,x_2$, $y=x_1b_1+x_2b_2$.

Comment: You might want to add that $b_3$ is independent of $b_1, b_2$ (since $B$ is invertible) and thus $x_3 = 0$.

Comment: @Richard I see how b3 is independent of b1, b2 as B is invertible but can't the same be said about b1 and b2? For example, b1 and b2 each are independent of b3; now this won't make x1 and x2 = 0 would it?

Comment: No, since $y$ is in the span of $b_1$ and $b_2$. This simply means that you can write $y$ as $x_1b_1+x_2b_2$ for a specific choice of $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Answer (score 0):

In the $\mathbb{R^3}$ vector space we can take any $2$ vectors and use then to form a set of $3$ linearly independent vectors to form the basis of $\mathbb{R^3}$. A basis spans $\mathbb{R^3}$. So we can get $b_3$ from the linear combination of $b_1$ and $b_2$ and a $3rd$ linearly independent vector. This implies that $b_3$ can be written in form $b_3=c_1b_1+c_2b_2$. Now you can substitute this and observe why $x_3=0$.